# Shell - If a new file is created, copy the second newest one somewhere

Tags: file, shell, copy, redhat, monitor

I am learning shell scripting and hit a wall of sorts. I am trying to write a shell script that will monitor a folder and copy files as they are being rendered locally to a network drive. The idea is that the files will copy as the render is going automatically.

Pesudo

```
--------------------------------------
folder = /home/user1/Desktop/myFolder

if (there is a new file in the folder) 

   newfile = myfile.004.tga
   fileNum = regularExpressionFunction(newfile)
   secondFile = myfile.$fileNum.tga //find the second newest file, so this would be      
                                    //myfile.003.tga

   cp secondFile /networkmount/
```

Comment: In general, this is not likely to go well. If you move a file within the same filesystem on UNIX, the inode is reattached to the new location, so further writes will go there -- but that's not the case when you cross between local and remote mounts, so further changes to the local file won't be represented remotely unless you copy it again.

Comment: That said -- if you want to have a script triggered by filesystem events, see incron: http://inotify.aiken.cz/

Comment: ...as for newest / second newest / etc, see BashFAQ #3:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003 -- the examples that do array indexing are what you want, since they're trivially modified to retrieve the second-latest time rather than the very latest time.

Comment: All that said, a great deal of care needs to be taken here to avoid race conditions -- that is, gracefully handling any cases when the contents of the filesystem change between when you inspect its state and when you operate on it. It's because of the amount of care needed to handle such things cautiously that I'm only providing comments with pointers, rather than an answer I'm willing to stand behind.

Answer (score 0):

You could script this yourself, but it's probably better to use an existing tool.

I would use `lsyncd`. It will copy the new files as they are created, and then copy the increments as they occur. You can adjust the delay setting to stop it doing this too aggressively, if necessary.